# Clarifying the example of large firms tilt to cooperate after shocks of competition in game theory?

Tags: game-theory

I am reading the example of large firms' operation when finking option is given [here](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/nash-game/).

> A "large" player who suffers disproportionately more from complete
> finking may act cooperatively even when the small fry are finking.
> Thus Saudi Arabia acts as a swing producer in OPEC, cutting its output
> to keep prices high when others produce more; and the United States
> bears a disproportionate share of the costs of its military alliances.
> Finally, if the group as a whole will do better in its external
> relations if it enjoys internal cooperation, then the process of
> biological or social selection may generate instincts or social norms
> that support cooperation and punish cheating.

Regarding the last sentence, I understand that if the firms already colluded together, in a more competition market, they will enjoy continue their cooperation because the cooperation has been established and maintained for a long time( process of social selection may generate instincts or social norms that support cooperation and punish cheating)

However, I cannot understand the example of Saudi Arabia and US as above, could you please explain it to me?